# How to load a script synchronously with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, requirejs

I am using RequireJS in ASP.NET. There is a user control that includes a script file, and registers a startup script in order to initialize itself. Here's the generated code:

```
<script src="script/UserControls/myctrl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myCtrl1_init() {
    // initialize control
    // *JS ERROR* because myctrl.js hasn't run yet
    Sys.Application.remove_load(myCtrl1_init);
}
Sys.Application.add_load(myCtrl1_init);
</script>
```

The myctrl.js file looks something like this:

```
require(['script/dep1', 'script/dep2'], function(dep1, dep2) {      
    MyCtrl = function () {
    };
    MyCtrl.init = function(id) {
        dep1.doSomething();
    }
};
```

So, the problem is that startup script runs before the myctrl.js file has had a chance to run. Currently, the require call uses a callback function, which obviously doesn't run until later, and this is the problem... the script returns and the browser continues to the startup script before MyCtrl has been created.

I have tried simply calling `require(['script/dep1', 'script/dep2']);` at the top of the file, but that doesn't block either, and the script fails because the dependencies haven't loaded yet. The dependencies are modules, by the way, e.g. they use `define()`.

Is there a way to load a script file synchronously with RequireJS? The API documentation says that "Using RequireJS in a server-side JavaScript environment that has synchronous loading should be as easy as redefining require.load()", but I have no idea what this means.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the script tag for require.js is above the contents you mention. If so, then I would convert myctrl.js to be a module (use "define('myctrl', ....)" instead of "require(.." inside it), then in the inline script tag content do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["myctrl"], function () {
    function myCtrl1_init() {
        // initialize control
        // *JS ERROR* because myctrl.js hasn't run yet
        Sys.Application.remove_load(myCtrl1_init);
    }
    Sys.Application.add_load(myCtrl1_init);
});
</script>
```

I am not familiar with ASP.NET, so I am not sure if it is OK to do those Sys.Application calls in a callback that may fire after DOMContentLoaded, but the above is the general idea.

There is no way to synchronously load a script in the browser with RequireJS, a callback method like above needs to be used. The require.load() information was for developers that want to make RequireJS adapters that run in sync environments (basically non-browser JS environments).

Comment: So, do the whole initialization asynchronously, eh? Seems reasonable, but can I count on the DOM having finished loading by the time myCtrl1_init fires?

Comment: If you want to be sure that myCtrl1_init is fired after DOM ready, then wrap the code with require.ready(). require(["myctrl"], function () { require.ready(function () { function myCtrl1_init.....

Comment: Can the optimizer load scripts synchronously? I need to access a window object for another app with it.